# Include works, readfile doesn't

Tags: php, wordpress, readfile

I'm experiencing odd behaviour loading a html file. `require_once`, `include` etc. works:

```
require_once 'suche.htm';
```

but `readfile` or `file_get_contents` won't

```
return file_get_contents('suche.htm');
```

> Warning: readfile(suche.htm): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in /var/www/vhosts/h...

Comment: Hi, you need check if file exist and then check if file has permissions to read.

Comment: thanks for the hint, how do I define readability of my files in a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time to [read the fine manual](http://php.net/manual/function.readfile.php)

> **Description**
>   `int readfile ( string $filename [, bool $use_include_path = false [, resource $context ]] )`

Note the second argument

> **`use_include_path`**
>   You can use the optional second parameter and set it to **TRUE**, if you want to search for the file in the [include_path](http://php.net/manual/ini.core.php#ini.include-path), too.

[`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/function.file-get-contents.php) has the same argument.

You would need to set that to `true` if you want `readfile` / `file_get_contents` to use the same path resolution as `require` / `include`.

---

Note, `readfile` does **not** return a string so you cannot use the result in `htmlentities`

---

#### UPDATE

In my opinion, it's much better to use an explicit file path, relative to the current PHP script file. For example

```
file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../suche.htm');
```

See http://php.net/manual/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: thank you, that solved it, I didn't expect it to be in any "include_path". I'll go rtfm ;) Note: I just used require_once for testing/debugging

Comment: any idea why get_include_path(); just returns `.:`

Comment: @Basti because that's what it's configured to be

Comment: so what is the meaning of a .: directory and why does it find my file in there? as soon as I move the file one directory up, I can't find it anymore. `../suche.html, true` doesn't work. this filesystem thing doesn't work at all for me :(

Comment: @Basti Well, `:` is just a path separator so ignore that. `.` refers to the current directory of the **entry point** PHP script. With Wordpress, that's probably `index.php` in the root application directory. I've updated my answer with a more robust solution

Comment: Now I understand it better and it works, I appreciate your help so much, thank you!